# What is the time complexity for the given C++ code?

Tags: c++, time-complexity, big-o

What is the time-complexity of the code fragment?

```
for (i = 0; i < N * N; i += N)
    k++;
```

I am not sure if it is N^2 or N since N is added to i in each loop.

Comment: `O(N)`, since that's how many iterations of the loop are performed, each doing `O(1)` work. Though an optimizing compiler might be able to transform this into `i = N*N; k += N;`, which would of course run in `O(1)` time.

Comment: @Igor that sounds suspiciously like an answer ;)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thank you for the answer! could you explain the time-complexity of this code fragment also?                                                                                                 
for ( i = 1; i < N ; i *= 5 )
for ( j = M / 2; j < M; j++ )
k++;

Comment: That's a different question. But also, these questions might be more suited for [cs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/), instead of Stack Overflow.

Comment: The outer loop performs `O(log N)` iterations. For each of those, there are `O(M)` iterations of the inner loop. Each of those performs `O(1)` work. Put together, that's `O(M*log N)`

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of above program is O(n), as there is only one 'for' loop.

The order of nesting of 'for' loops provides a rough estimation of the worst case complexity.

(Please refer the comment from Cigien below for more information)

**A rough estimation of worst-case complexity:**

If there are 2 for-loops with one nested inside the other, then the complexity may become o(n^2).

If there are 3 nested loops, then the complexity may become O(n^3)

...

**An example of O(n^2) complexity:**

```
for ( i = 1; i < P ; i ++ ) {
    for ( j = 1; j < Q; j++ ) {
        // some simple statements only
    }
}
```

**An example of O(n^3) complexity:**

```
for ( i = 1; i < P ; i ++ ) {
    for ( j = 1; j < Q; j++ ) {
        for ( k = 1; k < R; k++ ) {
            // some simple statements only
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The number does not need to correlate to the complexity. Also only one for loop can have `O(n²)`.

Comment: Counting nested loops is only a crude approximation of big-Oh at best. Your loops are `O(PQ)`, and `O(PQR)`, and P, Q, R, might be very different. Also, the `some simple statements only` can make a lot of difference, if they modify loop variables at all.

Comment: Thanks Cigien. I updated the answer as per the review.